# Customize collection radio buttons simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I customised my collection radio buttons of my form, everything work when the value is a simple strings choice but i dont success to save the select value when its this type of field

Original field

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:negociateur, Nego.where(user: current_user), :first_name, :first_name) %>
```

What i tried to do

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <% @negos.where(user: current_user).each do |n| %>
            <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
              <input id="bien_negociateur_true" name="bien[negociateur]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value= '<% n.first_name %>' /* the problem is here */ /> <%= n.first_name %>
            </label>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to save the "nego.id" or "nego.first_name"?

Comment: The first name @SebastiánPalma

Comment: Why don't you try `<%= %>` instead `<%%>` in the value attribute?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work, when i do that i cant submit the form, nothing happend when i click on submit and i dont have rollback or error message @SebastiánPalma

Comment: Why are you moving away from *simple_form*? Forget about the ERB, what's the HTML output of both the *simple_form* and your own implementation?